# Android: httppost Illegal character in query at index

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to parse the json returned from graph facebook, a feed from a page.
The url is something like this: https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/feed?access_token=MyAppId|MySecretKey&limit=10.

But I'm getting the error: Illegal character in query at index 7. The character at index 77 it's the "|". My code:

```
private JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Making HTTP request
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = "";
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
```

If I replace the URL, using the encoder, like this:

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/feed?access_token=MyAppId" + URLEncoder.encode("|", "UTF-8") + "mySecretKey&limit=10";
```

I receive the error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

But If I copy and paste the original URL, it's returning successfully the JSON

How can I send correctly the url on this case?

Comment: Just to make sure this is not a simple typo case: there is a typo on `acess_token` on the code using encoder. It should be `access_token`.

Comment: Your question title does not describe the problem. Seems it's an authentication issue.

Comment: Either that, or try using `HttpGet`, since when you copy-pasted the URL on browser, it's actually done with HTTP GET, not HTTP POST. (Not sure, but it won't hurt to try)

Comment: Andrew, you're correct! Epic fail...HTTPGET solved the problem.